# How to combine hadoop mappers output to get single result

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have about 170 GB data. I have to analyze it using hadoop 2.7.3. There are 14 workers. I have to find total of unique MIME type of each document e.g. total number of documents that are text/html type. When I run mapreduce job(written in python), Hadoop returns many output files instead of single one that I am expecting. I think this is due to many workers that process some data seprately and give output. I want to get single output. Where is the problem. How I can restrict hadoop to give single output (by combining all small output files).

Comment: You can set the setnumreducetasks(1)  to get a single output i believe

Comment: can you be more specific? what is the desired output format like? what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You can merge end file using hadoop **getmerge** command when you retrieve your data from hdfs:

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output/reduce/ /localcatalog/mergedresult.txt
```

Each mapper and reducer will generate a separate file and by decreasing the number of mappers and reducers you will decrease the level of parallelism of your job. I think instead of restricting the reducer to single output the best way would be to get the merged result from hdfs using provided command.

Comment: I think merge will cause duplicates e.g. a key text/html will exist in each output file. In the final output, it should be the sum of all.

Comment: @Shafiq You will not have duplicates as Reducer will group your data by key and distribute this sequentially among your reducer jobs. So you will have non-intersecting ranges without any duplicates. getmerge will just combine them into single file.

Comment: @Shafiq Alex's answer is correct for the current problem statement. What you have commented is different to the original question. "I have to find total of unique MIME type of each document" is not clear

Comment: Brother let me to verify this with some prototype. Then I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

your job is generating 1 file per mapper, you have to force a reducer phase using 1 reducer to do this, you can accomplish this  emitting the same key in all the mappers.

Answer (score 1):

Make your mapper to emit for each document processed  - `(doc-mime-type, 1)` then count up all such pairs at reduce phase. In essence, it is a standard word count exercise except your mappers emit 1s for each doc's mime-type.

Regarding number of reducers to set: Alex's way of merging reducers' results is preferable as allows to utilize all your worker nodes at reduce stage. However, if job to be run on 1-2 nodes then just one reducer should work fine.